# Route mapping tool - INSERTING a point

Tags: bikeroutes, maps, planning

I'm kind of frustrated by this, because after long time of internet searching, I found none that would satisfy my needs.

The problem is that I want to HAND-DRAW my route by first clicking it's endpoints, then refining the route in between.  So, I need a tool that will have ONE feature that all other tools lack - INSERTING a point between two points already in place.  Of course, it has to work ON google maps in satellite mode, so I can map across the fields and so on.

I don't care for an algorithm, since it is useless - I'm not following charted roads.

BTW: HAND-DRAW above means to draw it by hand on a computer, not on a paper :)

Comment: I'm wondering if this would be a better fit with the Geographic Information Systems SE site than this one since it has potential for wider application than just bicycling. http://gis.stackexchange.com/ You also might get better answers there.

Comment: @jimirings I posted it here since I find the problem very common and PRETTY obvious.  ALL route planers lack that SIMPLE option - ...  I wonder why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [ridewithgps](http://ridewithgps.com/) to build your map. It allows you to drag waypoints off the main route and re-routes (can be used without auto routing as well if you prefer).  You'll have to pay if you want to print from their site.  However, you can print a cue sheet free or export the saved map in GPX or TCX format to print with another application or website that accepts these uploads.

Comment: This is total winner, I spend last 2 hours creating a route of 90 km that I plan to ride soon.  Thanks!

Comment: Logged via Facebook, simple subscription form, works great!

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but Google Maps ALREADY allows for point insertion, by means of "breaking" one segment in two.

Instead of using the navigation directions, click the "My places" button in the sidebar, then "Create Map". The drawing tools appear on the map:

[image: Google Map drawing tools]

While editing a path, if you hover over a segment, the midpoints of each segment appear as dim knots. If you click and drag, they become "actual" node points that can be dreagged around. Besides that, each of both newborn segments now show their midpoint, allowing for further breakdown:

[image]

By the way, one MAJOR problem of Google Maps is that it doesn't allow (as far as I know) for connecting two separate paths into a single one (that can be done only by manually editing KML, very cumbersome).

By the way, if you have interest, an excelent track editor is [GPSTrackmaker](http://www.gpstm.com/index.php?lang=en), the non-PRO version is free, doesn't expire and is very powerful and robust.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use [gmap-pedometer.com](http://gmap-pedometer.com), which allows you to either automatically or manually connect point on google maps to create your own routes regardless of road, trail, or anything. You can create an account and save your routes, export them to alternative gps devices, etc. It's very handy and there are folks that use it for mapping cyclocross races among other things. Here is an example map with manual route:

http://www.gmap-pedometer.com/?r=5707827

Comment: Inserting a node inside a route?

Comment: ah, I understand what you're after now. Yes, Benzo's suggestion is better for your intended purpose. It does allow to create a start and end point and then drag the path to be adjusted to your needs, while gmap-pedometer is good for plotting out a manual or semi-automatic path but lacks the capability of making two points and adjusting the course between after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

[BikeRouteToaster](http://www.bikeroutetoaster.com/Course.aspx) can be a bit fiddly, but can do exactly this:

- Uncheck "auto routing"
- Click "course point"
- Add your main points (start and end, or multiple)
- Select one of the markers by clicking on it
- Press the "Insert Before" or "Insert After" button
- Click to add points (you can change to "track points" and they have more subtle markers)

In the "Summary" tab you can get distance/elevation info, and export to various files (gpx/tcx)